# For given bundle $E\to X$ find $\xi\to Y$ such that $\pi_*ch(\xi)=ch(E)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, grothendieck-riemann-roch

Let $\pi:X\to Y$ a projective morphism and $F\to X$ a vector bundle. The Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch theorem states that
$$\pi_*(ch(F)td(\pi))=ch(\pi_!F)$$
where $td(\pi)$ denotes the relative Todd class.

My question is the following. Assume that $F\to X$ satisfies $\pi_!F=E$ for some bundle $E\to Y$. I am looking for a vector bundle $\xi\to X$ such that
$$\pi_*(ch(\xi))=ch(\pi_!F)=ch(E).$$
Is there a hope to be able to find such a $\xi$?

Answer (score 2):

Not always. For a counter-example, take for $\pi $ a $\mathbb{P}^1\!$-fibration which is not a projective bundle (such a fibration exists for instance on any surface with $p_g\neq 0$), and take $F=\mathscr{O}_X$, so that $E=\mathscr{O}_Y$. The vector bundle $\xi $ should satisfy $\pi _*c_1(\xi )=1$, which means that $c_1(\xi )$ restricted to a fiber of $\pi $ has degree 1. This would imply that $\pi $ is a projective bundle, contrary to the hypothesis.

Comment: I am interested specifically in the case where $X\to Y$ is a projective bundle (that is the projectivization of a vector bundle). Is there a positive result in that case?