# For a given $E\to X$ find $\xi\to \mathbb{P}E^*$ such that $\pi_*\operatorname{ch}(\xi)=\operatorname{ch}(E)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, grothendieck-riemann-roch

$\DeclareMathOperator\ch{ch}$This is a specification of the question [For given bundle $E\to X$ find $\xi\to Y$ such that $\pi_*ch(\xi)=ch(E)$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416908/for-given-bundle-e-to-x-find-xi-to-y-such-that-pi-ch-xi-che).

Let $E\to X$ be a holomorphic vector bundle over a compact Kahler manifold and $\pi:\mathbb{P}(E^*)\to X$ its prejectivization. Denote by $\mathcal{O}_E(1)\to\mathbb{P}(E^*)$ the hyperplane bundle. It is well known that $\pi_!\mathcal{O}_E(1)=E$ and therefore by Grothendieck–Riemann–Roch
$$\pi_*(\ch(\mathcal{O}_E(1))td(\pi))=\ch(\pi_!\mathcal{O}_E(1))=\ch(E).$$
I wonder whether there exists (maybe in specific cases) a bundle $\xi\to \mathbb{P}(E^*)$ such that
$$\pi_*\ch(\xi)=\ch(E).$$